# Call function passed as an argument with arguments

Tags: java

I have a function, which takes a function and string as arguments, I want to call this function with the string argument and return the result.

Something like this:

```
public static String mainFunc(Callable func, String s) {
    return func.call(s); // Error
}

mainFunc(SomeObject::instanceMethod, s)
```

But as you can see it is not working. Please note that I don't necessarily need to use Callable, it can be any other interface.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @Jarrod that duplicate is not what the question is asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `Callable` takes no parameters.

If it takes a `String` and returns a `String`, it's a `Function<String, String>` (or, more generally, a `Function<? super String, ? extends String>`).

```
public static String mainFunc(Function<String, String> func, String s) {
  return func.apply(s);
}
```

Although, there's not very much point in this method: just invoke `func.apply` directly.

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for the edit, but please take care not to stomp my edits.

Comment: I don't think I can control that on mobile. Sorry

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks